# Unable to launch WebLogic Admin Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, weblogic

Just a lil background, I need to install WebLogic on RHEL EC2 instance and this EC2 instance only accessible via bastion host windows server. Both JumpHost and RHEL EC2 server doesnt have internet connection. So in order to perform WebLogic installation I would have to RDP into JumpHost and from there, SSH into EC2 RHEL instance.

Problems:

I've installed WebLogic at one of my EC2 RHEL 7 instance, and I've verified with curl http://localhost:7001/console to ensure the weblogic server is up. Now I'm trying to visit it at Jump host, I tried `http://<ec2-instance-ip>:7001/console` but doesnt work.

what have I done is I've checked Network ACL and Security Group of my EC2 Server, ensure that traffic from Jump Host has opened. What else could I be missing?

Comment: "http://:7001/console" is of course not a valid URL. "It doesn't work" is not an acceptable problem description; what is the exact error message? Try curl on the weblogic system with the other URL (i.e. not using localhost).

Comment: @wurtel: It was SO's formatting issue. It doesn't work meaning couldn't access the portal from JH. No error message, and tried to curl from JH, not working too.

Comment: With curl I would expect at least something like "connection refused" or "connection timed out". No error message at all is very strange.